# Can we add Preview Functionality in CME for DD4T based Application

Tags: dd4t, templating, preview

We see json Data if we preview any component Presentation, Can we have same preview functionality as we had in web form based application ?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how current this information is, but according to [this blogpost](http://blog.trivident.com/previewing-pages-with-dd4t/), yes you can.

There's some template and webapp changes needed to get it to work, they're detailed in the post I linked to.

Comment: I think following the above post we can enable page preview only. We cannot have component presentation preview. But I guess we tweak it further to have CP preview for DD4T.

Comment: Component Presentations will need the context of where they appear to have a realistic preview. It might be worth either offering a "simple" preview with rich text and limited styles or consider using Topology Manager to resolve all the places a Component Presentation is embedded on a page. Without a CMS page, though, there isn't an easy programmatic way to know where  Dynamic Component Presentations appear.

Comment: The blogpost is not up to date, but the approach is still the same. You may need to update the code a bit.